# Valid Supplier for collect method of stream

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I was just trying to create somewhat similar to `Collectors.toList()` of my own but it doesn't seem to work

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShipmentTracingDTO {

boolean destination = false;

public ShipmentTracingDTO(Boolean destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}

public ShipmentTracingDTO() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ShipmentTracingDTO> tracings = new ArrayList<>();
    tracings.add(new ShipmentTracingDTO(true));
    tracings.add(new ShipmentTracingDTO(true));
    tracings.add(new ShipmentTracingDTO(false));
    tracings.add(new ShipmentTracingDTO(false));
    ArrayList<ShipmentTracingDTO> newTracings = new ArrayList<>();

// Error coming for ArrayList::new : The constructed object of type ArrayList is 
//incompatible with the descriptor's return type: R

    tracings.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, (left, right) -> left.add(right), (left, right) -> {
        left.addAll(right);
        return left;
    });
}

private boolean getDestination() {

    return destination;
}
```

}

My question is if `ArrayList::new` doesn't work here, what will work. I tried different variation but none seems to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change it like so,

```
tracings.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, (left, right) -> left.add(right), (left, right) -> {
    left.addAll(right);
});
```

What you need is a `BiConsumer` NOT a `BinaryOperator`. What you are passing above is a `BinaryOperator`.

Here's an example `BinaryOperator`.

```
BinaryOperator<List<Integer>> s = (left, right) -> {
            left.addAll(right);
            return left;
};
```

As a good engineering practice, always prefer method references to lambdas. So here's the enhanced version using method references in place of lambdas.

```
tracings.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);
```

Comment: `(left, right) -> left.add(right)` can be replaced by `List::add` and `(left, right) -> left.add(right)` by `List::addAll`.

Comment: Yes, but it is not directly related to the question.

Comment: The OP asked *"what will work"*. The method references will work as well as lambdas. But I would prefer to show best practices along with explanation, not just fixing the compilation issue.

Comment: @ETO I have updated the answer as per the suggestion.

Comment: And that’s basically what `Collectors.toList()` does internally, though the specification gives room to do it differently (i.e. not to return an `ArrayList` but another `List` implementation). But when you use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`, you get exactly that. The confusion may stem from `Collector.of(…)` whose merge function *is* a binary operator: `tracings.stream().collect(Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::add, (l,r) -> { l.addAll(r); return l; })`. This allows potential optimizations, i.e. `(l,r) -> { if(l.isEmpty()) return r; 
    l.addAll(r); return l; }`

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be looking for:

```
tracings.stream()
        .collect(ArrayList::new, 
                 ArrayList::add, 
                 ArrayList::addAll);
```

which is the same as the lambda representation:

```
tracings.stream()
        .collect(ArrayList::new, 
                 (left, right) -> left.add(right), 
                 (left, right) -> left.addAll(right)); // notice no 'return'
```

**Reason**: The [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) expects a `BiConsumer` as an argument, which has a `accept` method with `void`return type.

Answer (score 1):

> I was just trying to create somewhat similar to Collectors.toList() of
>   my own but it doesn't seem to work

While the other answers specify what you've done wrong it's worth noting that if you're trying to create something similar to `toList()` but at the same time specify the type of list returned then I'd suggest using `toCollection` which is specifically made for this purpose.

```
tracings.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

although this is no better than:

```
new ArrayList<>(tracings);
```

which is shorter and more readable.